# How to generate a random sequence given a probability matrix of transitions?

Tags: python, matrix, probability, markov-chains

The script below produces a probability matrix for a given list:

```
transitions = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'D']

def rank(c):
   return ord(c) - ord('A')

T = [rank(c) for c in transitions]

#create matrix of zeros

M = [[0]*4 for _ in range(4)]

for (i,j) in zip(T,T[1:]):
   M[i][j] += 1

#now convert to probabilities:
for row in M:
   n = sum(row)
   if n > 0:
       row[:] = [f/sum(row) for f in row]

#print M:
for row in M:
   print(row)
```

**output**

```
[0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5]
[0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0]
[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5]
```

I now want to do the opposite, and make a new transition list of A B C D following the probability matrix.
How can I make this happen?

Comment: What is your expected output and how should this be achieved?

Comment: I think the idea is to generate a new random sequence, where given current letter A, the next one is A with probability 0, B with probability 0.5, C with probability 0, D with probability 0.5. So, using the weights of the matrix. It is not very clear what the first letter should be. Maybe just A, or maybe randomly with the same weights as the original sequence?

Comment: @TimStack, exactly what Johan said. The first letter can be random. So a random sequence of a given lenght, let's say 10 letters, following the brobability matrix, like Johan explained.

Comment: @JohanC, exactly!

Comment: Am I correct to understand you're constructing a Markov Model?

Comment: @Lina Does any of the answers solve the question you posed? If so, please consider to upvote and/or accept. If not, feel free to ask additional clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) function of the random library could be of help. As the question doesn't indicate how to choose the first letter, here it is chosen with the same probability as the contents of the original list.

Since Python 3.6 `random.choices` accepts a parameter with weights. It is not strictly necessary to normalize them.

```
import random

letter = random.choice(transitions)  # take a starting letter with the same weights as the original list
new_list = [letter]
for _ in range(len(transitions) - 1):
    letter = chr(random.choices(range(4), weights=M[rank(letter)])[0] + ord('A'))
    new_list.append(letter)
print(new_list)
```

The full code could be generalized somewhat to work with any kind of nodes, not just consecutive letters:

```
from _collections import defaultdict
import random

transitions = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'D']

nodes = sorted(set(transitions))  # a list of all letters used
M = defaultdict(int)  # dictionary counting the occurrences for each transition i,j)

for (i, j) in zip(transitions, transitions[1:]):
    M[(i, j)] += 1

# dictionary with for each node a list of frequencies for the transition to a next node
T = {i: [M[(i, j)] for j in nodes] for i in nodes}

# node = random.choice(transitions) # chose the first node randomly with the same probability as the original list
node = random.choice(nodes) # chose the first node randomly, each node with equal probability
new_list = [node]
for _ in range(9):
    node = random.choices(nodes, T[node])[0]
    new_list.append(node)

print(new_list)
```

Example output:`['D', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'B']`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are attempting to create a Markov Model.
I happen to have some experience with (Hidden) Markov Models as a bioinformatician student, and I would therefore use nested dictionaries to simplify working with the matrix. Note that I have imported the `numpy.random` function.

Hope this helps!

```
import numpy.random as rnd

alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
transitions = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'D']

# Create probability matrix filled with zeroes
# Matrix consists of nested libraries
prob_matrix = {}
for i in alphabet:
    prob_matrix[i] = {}
    for j in alphabet:
        prob_matrix[i][j] = 0.0

def rank(c):
   return ord(c) - ord('A')

# fill matrix with numbers based on transitions list
T = [rank(c) for c in transitions]
for (i,j) in zip(T,T[1:]):
    prob_matrix[alphabet[i]][alphabet[j]] += 1

# convert to probabilities
for row in prob_matrix:
   total = sum([prob_matrix[row][column] for column in prob_matrix[row]])
   if total > 0:
       for column in prob_matrix[row]:
           prob_matrix[row][column] /= total

# generate first random sequence letter
outputseq = rnd.choice(alphabet, None)

# generate rest of string based on probability matrix
for i in range(11):
    probabilities = [prob_matrix[outputseq[-1]][j] for j in alphabet]
    outputseq += rnd.choice(alphabet, None, False, probabilities)

# output generated sequence
print(outputseq)
```

Comment: thank you so much! Is there a way I can make my 'alphabet' non-alphabetic? Let's say using the letter B, F, A, L, T? When I change my letters now I get an error on the line '''prob_matrix[alphabet[i]][alphabet[j]] += 1'''.

Comment: @Lina the `transitions` list must contain the same set of characters as the `alphabet` list does. Have you made sure this is the case?

Comment: Yes this all the case. It's all fine if I add an 'E' and then an 'F' but if I would like to add an L by example it gives me an error message, so I thought maybe the list must be consecutive letters of the alphabet?

Comment: The code breaks because of how you fill up the matrix initially. You will need to come up with another method, I don't know what your requirements are.